# Add In-App purchase price list in app description

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have In-App purchase in my app. Also, there are some auto-renewable products in it. Now, Apple has rejected my app for the below reason:

> Before You Submit
>
> We noticed that your Application Description did not fully meet the
>   terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in
>   Schedule 2, Section 3.8(b).
>
> Specifically, your Application Description did not include:
>
> 1. the price of the subscription.

Should i add a static price list in my app description or anything else is there I need to do ?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you mention the IAP/subscription in your app description at all? Did you already submit your IAPs for review? (You have to do that separately)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Comment: what did u do ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow this steps:

1. Add Length of subscription in your description

> for ex: "subscription for 15 days"

2. Add price of the subscription

> ```
>     for ex: "price - 0.99$"
> ```

**Note :**

- If you feel there is some more additional information required to added than also add that.
- Make sure you must addd price & length of subscription in your description.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As all of the apps with auto-renewable subscription are doing, you also have to write about the in app purchase that are there in your app and their price.